# Raspberry Pi network can't be accessed outside of network

Tags: server

I set up a cloud using OneCloud on my Raspberry Pi, but I discovered that it can only be accessed within my home network. I cannot access it from anywhere else.

I used this tutorial: [Install OwnCloud on your Raspberry Pi](http://www.samhobbs.co.uk/2013/10/install-owncloud-on-your-raspberry-pi). Please help.

Answer (score 6):

You need to set up port forwarding on your router. Then you can use your (router's) public IP to access your raspberry pi from outside.

Comment: Ok, so I set up port forwarding and enabled it for my pi, but how do I access it? I'm sorry, I'm a complete noob at this.

Comment: With any computer connected through the same router, surf to whatsmyip.org, take down the ip-number shown, and try to connect to it on the port you forwarded.

Answer (score 2):

To access the OneCloud  from other networks you need a domain of your own. Seen from outside your home network, the raspberrypi will be not having the IP you gave it but a global address given to your router